# Getting question marks instead of domain information when using WHOIS command in terminal for google.com - Why is this happening?

Tags: whois

I'm trying to learn how to use whois, and when I type whois google.com in terminal, it doesn't show up the information about the domain but some question marks. Does anyone know why this happened? Thank you in advance!
[image: whois information in terminal]

Answer (score 0):

Solved: it's because the uni wifi banned my access to whois. After I change the wifi connection to my hotspot, it works. Cheers!